# Show a trivial fact about a congruence

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

We know that $$x^m\equiv x \pmod {2}$$
for any $x$ and $m≥1$.

Let us consider the congruence
$$x+y+z \equiv 0 \pmod {2}$$
If $x,y,z$ are all even then the above congruence holds true.
We know that (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/missouri-journal-of-mathematical-sciences/volume-8/issue-1/Residues---Part-II-Congruences-Modulo-Powers-of-2/10.35834/1996/0801026.full)

**Theorem. 1**: The integer $A$ is a quartic residue modulo $2^n$ if and only if $A =16k + 1$ for $k$ a nonnegative integer.

The exercise says: Show by using **Theorem. 1** the **trivial fact** that $$x+y+z \equiv 0 \pmod {2}$$ if $x$ and $y$ are odd and $z$ is even.

Now, to show this we proceed as follow:

The above congruence is equivalent to:
$$x^4 \equiv y+z \pmod {2}$$

Then there exist an integer $l$ verifying $y+z=16l+1$. Reducing this congruence modulo $2$ we get
$y^4 \equiv z+1 \pmod {2}$

Then there exist an integer $h$ verifying $z+1=16h+1$. Reducing this congruence modulo $2$ we get
$$z \equiv 0 \pmod {2}$$

Thus, we get the system

$$z  \equiv 0 \pmod {2}$$
$$y+z  \equiv 1 \pmod {2}$$

that is,
$$z  \equiv 0 \pmod {2}$$
$$y  \equiv 1 \pmod {2}$$

and from the first congruence we get
$$x  \equiv 1 \pmod {2}$$

The last **question** is: Is this method can find all the solutions with mixed parities.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: @fleablood: It is just a proof verification.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe is easier seeing that since $x$ and $y$ are even and $z$ is odd then
$x=2a+1, y=2b+1, z=2c$ for some $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ So
$$x+y+z=2a+1+2b+1+2c=2(a+b+c+1)\equiv 0\;mod\;2$$

Comment: But the question is about using Theorem.1

Comment: You should specifie it, I thought that it was only your attempt

Comment: Ok it is specified.